# Activate angular validators only if input is visible

Tags: angular, forms, angular-validator

I'm trying to get this to work but I don't know how, I have several inputs that are only displayed when the user needs them.But if they are activated, it must be necessary to fill them. So i got this

component.ts

```
    dataForm = new FormControl({
       myInput: new FormControl(null, Validators.required)
    })
```

component.html

```
<form [formGroup]="dataForm">
     <input formControlName="myInput" type="number" *ngIf="inputActive">

   <button type="submit" [disabled]="!dataForm.valid">
</form>
```

The problem I have is that when the inputActive variable is false and the input is not shown, the button is still disabled because the field is empty

And I want that when the input is not shown, its validators are not executed so that the button is enabled

Can anyone help me to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need to do is disable the control instead of or in addition to removing/hiding the form field. This is done by calling [`disable()`](https://angular.io/api/forms/AbstractControl#disable) on the control. We will use this together with the related [`disabled`](https://angular.io/api/forms/AbstractControl#disabled) property to achieve the desired effect.

```
@Component({
  // ...boilerplate 
})
export class MyComponent {
  constructor(readonly formBuilder: FormBuilder) {}

  dataForm = this.formBuilder.group({
    anotherInput: this.formBuilder.control(''), // see note
    myInput: this.formBuilder.control(null, Validators.required)
  });

  disableControl(control: AbstractControl) {
    control.disable();
  }
}
```

In the template

```
<form [formGroup]="dataForm">
  <input formControlName="myInput" type="number" 
    [hidden]="dataForm.controls.myInput.disabled">

  <input formControlName="anotherInput">

  <button type="submit" [disabled]="!dataForm.valid">Submit</button>
</form>

<button (click)="disableControl(dataForm.controls.myInput)" type="button"></button>
```

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-gxdykj?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

This also helps use organize the form since we don't have an `inputActive` property to maintain separately from form state.

Note that the whole form group will be considered disabled if *all* of its children are disabled.

Answer (score 1):

I had to deal with this recently myself.  I ended up creating a custom validator function like this

```
conditionalRequiredValidator(formControl: AbstractControl) {
    if (!formControl.parent) {
      return null;
    }
    if (inputActive) {
      return Validators.required(formControl);
    }
    return null;
  }
```

Then reference this function as a validator when you create the FormControl.

Finally, you have to set up a listener for the form control that has the `inputActive` value, and when its `valueChanges` call the forms built-in `updateValueAndValidity` function.

See more [here](https://medium.com/ngx/3-ways-to-implement-conditional-validation-of-reactive-forms-c59ed6fc3325)

Comment: I recently started using angular so I don't know where to put this :c

Comment: @PacManProgramador, when you create the form control, should look like this 'myInput: new FormControl(null, [this.conditionalRequiredValidator])`.  Might have to use `ViewChild` to get a reference to the form. When you have access to form, you can set up subscription, via `this.formRef.get('controlname').valueChanges.subscribe(value => ...)`

Answer (score 0):

You are waiting for a directive to behave like a component. An `input` is a directive when it is not set in the DOM. It is just that. But when you load a `component` you load all the logic with. 
 So I propose that you put your `input` in a component something like `app-input` than you set Tha validators which you want, any time you shown this component the validators will be automatically active.